# Getting validation on login form in CakePHP 2.2

Tags: php, cakephp

I have built a simple CakePHP app with a users login system and have hooked up the Cake Form plugin by Milesj.me (not sure if that's causing the problems).

However my validation seems to have applied itself to the login form as well as the signup form. So when I try and login, I am getting errors like 'Username already in use'.

Any ideas what would cause this? Has something changed in CakePHP that adds the validation to authentication forms as well?

**Also why am I having to hash the password in the model? I was under the impression that CakePHP hashed passwords automatically? And I've not needed to do it before. However If I don't do it, then it was saving the password in the DB as in and not hashed...**

Here is my view, controller and model:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.username',
    array('tabindex'=>1, 'autofocus',
    'label'=>array('class'=>'placeholder','text'=>'Username'))); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.password',
    array('tabindex'=>2, 'type'=>'password',
    'label'=>array('class'=>'placeholder','text' =>'Password' ))); ?>

    <div class="input button">
        <button class="orangeButton" tabindex="3" type="submit"><span class="icon login">Log in</span></button>
    </div>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

controller:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->data) {
        $this->User->set($this->request->data);

        if ($this->User->validates() && $this->Auth->login()) {
            if ($user = $this->Auth->user()) {
                $this->User->Profile->login($user['id']);
                $this->Session->delete('Forum');

                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: the calls to Profile model for login just saves some data for when last logged in and other stuff and doesn't actually do anything regarding authentication!**

and the model:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'User';

    public $hasOne = array(
        'Profile' => array('className' => 'Forum.Profile')
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Access' => array('className' => 'Forum.Access'), 
        'Moderator' => array('className' => 'Forum.Moderator')
    );

    public $validate = array(
        'email' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A valid email address is required'
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => array('email'),
                'message' => 'This is not a valid email address'
            ),
            'unique' => array(
                'rule' => array('isUnique'),
                'message' => 'This email is already in use'
            )
        ),
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            ),
            'unique' => array(
                'rule' => array('isUnique'),
                'message' => 'This username is already in use'
            ),
            'alphaNumeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('alphaNumeric'),
                'message' => 'Usernames must only contain letters and numbers'
            ),
            'between' => array(
                'rule' => array('between', 4, 20),
                'message' => 'Usernames must be between 4 and 20 characters long'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A password is required'
            )
        )
    );


    public function beforeSave()
    {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password']))
        {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: In Cake 2.X, the `AuthComponent` no longer automatically hashes every password - it was removed because it made tasks like validation more difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to your validation rules `'on' => 'create'`

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#on

Comment: Is this something that has changed recently in Cake? As I haven't seen validation work on login forms in the past...

Comment: Well.. if you are not adding nothing (create) on login, it should work. This will prevent the validation in any method that does not create records (update, delete, select..)

Comment: Maybe you should ask yourself, why is this validating? I have made a lot of logins with cakephp and as I remember, the validation is not working there.

Answer (score 0):

As per cakephp

> In case of multiple rules per field by default if a particular rule
>   fails error message for that rule is returned and the following rules
>   for that field are not processed.
>
> But if first rule doesn't fail, then it continue to evaluate second
>   rule.

You can remove particular validation by following way

```
$this->validator()->remove('username', 'unique');
```

Comment: I shouldn't be getting any validation on the login form! In all my other CakePHP apps I don't. So what's causing it here?

Comment: why you called `$this->User->validates()` ?

Comment: Very Strange. for debuggin, can you comment out this: `$this->User->Profile->login($user['id']);`

Comment: can you check form action in page view source